# Using listeners to catch errors in steps in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring and Spring Batch. I wrote a basic job that's supposed to repeat every 5 seconds. It has two steps, the first of which (`step1`) is supposed to fail every time. My aim was to see if the job would report these errors in `step1` and continue to `step2`. The approach I am using to catch errors in `step1` is below (using `listener`s). I would like some critique on how right/wrong my approach is.

This is my job configuration. It has one job which has two steps:

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    private StepExecutionListenerImpl stepExecutionListener;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .listener(this.stepExecutionListener)
                .tasklet(new Tasklet() throws Exception {
                    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                        throw new Exception("Step1 caused an exception");
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws InterruptedException {
                        System.out.println("Step2 is executing");
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1())
                .on("COMPLETED").to(step2()).end()
                .build();
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * *")
    public void runJob() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Job Started at :" + new Date());

        JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .toJobParameters();

        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job(), param);

        System.out.println("Job finished with status :" + execution.getStatus());
    }

   @Bean
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
       SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
       simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(this.jobRepository);
       return simpleJobLauncher;
    }
}
```

To cause an error in `step1`, I threw an exception in that step. I also added a `listener` in `step1` whose `afterStep()` method checks if any exceptions have occurred in that step, and if so, returns `ExitStatus.FAILED`. If no exceptions occur, it returns `ExitStatus.COMPLETED`. Below is the code for that:

```
@Component
public class StepExecutionListenerImpl implements StepExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        System.out.println("Before starting step");
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        List<Throwable> exceptions = stepExecution.getFailureExceptions();
        if(exceptions.isEmpty()) {
            return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
        } else {
            System.out.println("This step has encountered exceptions");
            exceptions.forEach(th -> System.out.println("Exception has occurred in job"));
            return ExitStatus.FAILED;
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to be working, since `step1` fails on each iteration of the job, and then a new iteration begins. So my question is, is this a good way of catching errors in Spring Batch jobs? Am I using listeners correctly?

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented `ItemReadListener`,`ItemProcessListener`,`ItemWriteListener` interfaces which contains methods like `onReadError`,`onProcessError`,`onWriteError`. These methods are invoked if there is any exception during the process of reading/processing/writing the records.