# Email Sender Tasklet Executes Only On Spring Batch Java Job Fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, spring-batch

I'm looking to get some guidance on how to create a email sender tasklet that will  only execute when the java job fails. i have custom system exceptions class that also stops the job. I have added the spring boot starter mail dependency into my pom. I'm stuck on creating the tasklet class. Basically i want a email to send whenever a exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a JobExecutionListenerSupport to listen to the job status on an event of your custom system exception that stops the job.

Send email notification can be configured in the listener instead of creating a new Tasklet step.

Below is a snippet of the JobCompletionListener which gets called on an event of completion of job, either successful or on the event of job failure,

```
public class JobCompletionListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobCompletionListener.class);

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            logger.info("Job execution completed successfully");
        } else {
            logger.error("Job execution did not complete successfully");

            // you can customize with the help of java mail service
            mailService.sendNotificationMailForFailure();
        }
    }

}
```

Below is a snippet of the Job Bean definition,

```
@Bean
public Job lifeCycleJob() throws Exception {


    Job job = jobBuilderFactory.get("lifeCycleJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
    .start(startFlow).next(step1()).next(step2()).next(endFlow).end()
    .listener(jobCompletionListener()).build();

    return job;
}


@Bean
public JobCompletionListener jobCompletionListener() {
    return new JobCompletionListener();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want a tasklet.  If you make it a Tasklet it will be a lot more work, and if the job fails the Tasklet would not exwecute any way.

I will be easier to create a Listener and put the email service call in the onError() method.

Listeners can be set at the Job, Step, Chunk, ItemReader, ItemProcessor, ItemWriter scopes levels.   In your case to catch an error you would likely you would want to create a Job listner and check the job status after it ends.   There are also specific onError() methods on some of the listeners.

Create your listener.

public class MyJobListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {

```
@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    if (jobExecution.getStatus() != BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
        // Send EMAIL call.
    }
}
```

}

Then attach the listner to the job.

```
@Bean
public MyJobListener listener() {
    return new MyJobListener();
}

@Bean
public Job demoJob(MyJobListener listner){
    return jobs.get("demoJob")
        .listener(listner)
        .start(stepOne())
        .next(stepTwo())
        .build();
}
```

Also see: 
[Using listeners to catch errors in steps in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216590/using-listeners-to-catch-errors-in-steps-in-spring-batch)